# ListView Binding not working

Tags: c#, xaml

Let's say that I have this kind of book class

```
class book{
    public List<string> Authors { get; set; }
}
```

and have a book manager like this one

```
class bookManager{
    private List<book> booksCollection;
    public bookManager(){
        //Populate booksCollection with data
    }
    public book getOneBook(int index){
        //return book with book.index = index
    }
}
```

I'm trying to Bind the Authors list into a ListView using Binding. But no data seem to be appear at the ListView. Here's how my xaml looks like

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding selectedBook.Authors}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="20" Text="●" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
                <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="20" Text="{Binding}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

and the C# behing the xaml looks like this

```
private book selectedBook;
public bookDetailPage(){
    this.selectedBook = new bookManager().getOneBook(selectedIndex);
}
```

Strangely, when i'm using x:Bind, it's work. Here the xaml file using x:Bind

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind selectedBook.Authors}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="x:String">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="20" Text="●" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
                <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="20" Text="{x:Bind }" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

1. Where do i do wrong with my Binding method?
2. Can someone explain as simple as possible to me regrading x:Bind vs Binding method?

For information, i'm using VS2015.

Comment: Your selectedBook is a field - it has to be a property.

Comment: See [Data binding overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt269383.aspx) and [Data binding in depth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt210946.aspx) for data binding in general and for the differences between `{Binding}` and `{x:Bind}`. In short, `{Binding}` only works with *public properties*, not fields.